# Abrir una ventana dentro de otra que esta en otro archivo en tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

No puedo abrir una ventana dentro de otra que esta en otro archivo, por ejemplo: Quiero hacer un juego pero quiero hacer una ventana principal donde agrego un boton y cuando lo presiono, me abra la otra ventana del juego y esta ultima ventana es de otro archivo.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from subprocess import call
import Fx2  
#Fx2 es el nombre del segundo archivo

def opne_window():
    app.destroy()
    
    call(["Fx2.py"])
    


app = Tk()
app.title("GAME")
buttonExample = tk.Button(app, 
              text="Open window",
              command=opne_window)
buttonExample.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pues si te refieres al **código** de una ventana escrito en otro `.py`, puedes **importar** una función que llame lo necesario en el otro archivo desde tu archivo principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código de dos archivos (`application.py` y `fx2.py`) podría servir:

```python
# application.py
import tkinter as tk

from fx2 import Fx2

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(self)
        self.button["text"] = "Open"
        self.button["command"] = self.open
        self.button.pack()

    def open(self):
        Fx2(self.master)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

```python
# fx2.py
import tkinter as tk

class Fx2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.message = tk.Message(self, text="Hello")
        self.message.pack()
```

Se puede ejecutar usando `python3 application.py`.

`application.py` es el archivo principal. Importa `Fx2` definida en `fx2.py`. Define una ventana que tiene un único botón que al presionarse muestra una nueva ventana (`Toplevel`) definida en el segundo archivo `fx2.py`.

`fx2.py` es el archivo secundario. Define una ventana que tiene un mensaje.

Este código está basado en [este ejemplo](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) de la documentación de Tkinter.